# Error when compiling the Linux Kernel version 4.14.51

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling

Not sure what happened here.  I'm trying to upgrade my Linux kernel from 4.9.x to 4.14.x and the below happened:

```
In file included from arch/x86/decode.c:26:0:
arch/x86/../../elf.h:22:18: fatal error: gelf.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gelf.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
mv: cannot stat ‘/usr/src/linux-4.14.51/tools/objtool/arch/x86/.decode.o.tmp’: No such file or directory
make[4]: *** [/usr/src/linux-4.14.51/tools/objtool/arch/x86/decode.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [arch/x86] Error 2
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-4.14.51/tools/objtool/objtool-in.o] Error 2
make[1]: *** [objtool] Error 2
make: *** [tools/objtool] Error 2
```

Any ideas what happened here (other than the obvious)?  Should "`gelf.h`" already be on my computer? Or in the kernel tarball?

I downloaded vanilla 4.14.51 from kernel.org - I've compiled my own (unmodified) vanilla kernel successfully, repeatedly, for 14 years now, but this is new.

My PC is a Dell laptop with Core2 i5 (64-bit) with Slackware 14.1 -- I upgraded the stock 3.17.x with 4.4.x several years ago, and more recently to 4.9.x (currently 4.9.109).

I *do* have libelf installed:

```
me@mylaptop:~$ locate gelf.h
/usr/include/libelf/gelf.h

me@mylaptop:~$ ls /var/log/packages/*elf*
/var/log/packages/libelf-0.8.13-x86_64-2
```

### ADDENDUM

When trying 4.14.55 last night, I noted that the directory in which the kernel build script expects to see "gelf.h" is in the kernel source tree, not the regular `/usr/include`.

That being said, the corresponding directory in my (running) 4.9.x source tree does *not* have any `.o` nor `.ko` files.  Obviously there's a config item enabled in 4.14.x that I don't have enabled in 4.9.x.

I've tried configuring 4.14.x as close to my working 4.9.x as possible; I am aware of some new options, but generally I try to keep the configurations the same between intermediate kernel versions.

That being said, I don't know what config option it is that would want to see the header files in `linux-4.14.*/tools/objtool/arch/x86/`... **Any ideas?**

Comment: Perhaps check that the location of gelf.h is in the #include path, and that the user running `make` has access rights to it (and the folder)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834152/what-is-default-path-for-header-file-included-in-c-program

Comment: My copy of gelf.h is in /usr/include and it is from the (Centos 7) package elfutils-libelf-devel.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the following package:

```
libelf
```

It provides the `gelf.h` header file and others. Perhaps you just never installed it on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

The above `#include` is looking for the file **exactly at** `/usr/include/` while your file is located elsewhere, in `/usr/include/libelf/`. This won't work.

Please **either**:

- create a symlink (preferrable), `sudo ln -s libelf/gelf.h /usr/include/gelf.h`
- copy the file, e.g. `sudo cp -a /usr/include/libelf/gelf.h /usr/include`
- fix the include, e.g. `#include <libelf/gelf.h>`

Anyways, it's a packaging issue in Slackware. This include file is installed incorrectly.